# How to change order in billing address

Tags: contribution-page

I'm using Civicrm 5.13.4 on Drupal 7.67.

I want to change the order of the address fields and bring "postal_code" upper in the list when using the "pay later option".
I was able to find for online payment but not for this option.
It's also already set in localization/address. Is there a way to modify this?

[image]

Thanks
Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a quick hack, you can change it in CRM/Core/Payment/Manual.php in the getBillingAddressFields() function. Just rearrange the order in the return statement.

To do it without a hack you might be able to use the buildForm hook in an extension. You could also move it with some jquery but that's also a bit of a hack.

Comment: Thank you Demerit, the quick hack was exactly what I needed