# How can I add Company to billing/pay later fields?

Tags: fields, paylater

When I activate pay later and force pay later address input on an event I get some fields displayed.

How can I add "Company" to those fields?

I used the hack in [How to change order in billing address](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30842/how-to-change-order-in-billing-address) to tweak the ordering.

The return in `CRM/Core/Payment/Manual.php` looks like this:

```
      return [
        'first_name' => 'billing_first_name',
        'last_name' => 'billing_last_name',
        'street_address' => "billing_street_address-{$billingLocationID}",
        'postal_code' => "billing_postal_code-{$billingLocationID}",
        'city' => "billing_city-{$billingLocationID}",
        'country' => "billing_country_id-{$billingLocationID}",
        'state_province' => "billing_state_province_id-{$billingLocationID}",
      ];
```

I'm not sure what the values in this returned table actually means or how it is used, but I could not find anything like `billing_company` or `billing_organisation` when `grep`-ing the PHP sources.

Is there a way to add the company information to the "pay later" form?

Comment: how about 'current_employer'?

Comment: Adding `'company' => "current_employer"` displays the field, but it does not get saved in  the billing information.

Comment: The billing info should really be a profile, rather than hard-coded: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2761

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to add a new field to the billing address instead of changing the core file. But you could do via custom extension using buildform hook

Comment: And how would I integrate that into the Pay Later flow? And get the result of that form into the payments for the participants? Could you expand on your answer, please.

Comment: As I said it's not easy, But you can definitely achieve this using hooks rather overriding core. Will need to debug the hook params and add the field accordingly. The data will be stored against the contact however it won't appear on a single screen will need to do few clicks to see the data